# DocuSign Connect (REST) configured but no callback made or logged

Tags: docusignapi

In my developer DocuSign sandbox instance I have created a REST based Connect callback that should be fired recipient signed/completed, as per the documentation.

When I sign a Clickwrap document, via the Test ClickWrap functionality in the admin portal and via my calling web site, I am able to sign the Clickwrap document but the Connect callback is not called. There is also no entry in the Connect logs showing success or failure.

It is as if the Connect functionality is not enabled, but it shows as enabled and active on https://admindemo.docusign.com/connect.

Anybody seen this problem and know the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect doesn't fire for Clickwraps.

Comment: A misunderstanding on my part of what the Connect callback supports and does not support

Answer (score 0):

Try to test both separately. First test your connect by creating sample envelope. The easiest is to use something like *webhook.site* as your callback handler. Update your webhook config with the URL from *webhook.site*. Then test your Clickwrap. At this point you will have better idea where to concentrate your efforts